# Shell Arguments Not Being Passed to Java Class Correctly

Tags: java, shell, unix, parameter-passing

I wrote a short shell script that takes in parameters, checks them (because they're "optional" and if they're empty it sets default values), and them passes them to a Java class on the server.  Basically, like so:

```
x=${2:-'Default'}
y=${3:-'Default Name Has Spaces'}
echo \"$x\"
echo \"$y\"
java -d64 -ms3G -mx3G -cp example.jar -Djava.security.policy=policy com.example.JavaClass $1 \"$x\" \"$y\"
```

However, when the shell makes the call to the Java class, I just get back that (if the above defaults are used) "argument Name is not recognized".

With the escaped-quotes around the `echo` on lines 3 and 4, I see that the variables ARE set correctly and they're echoed out like so: `"Default"` and `"Default Name Has Spaces"`, yet even with the escaped quotes in the Java call, they seem to be passing as more than two arguments -- it's like they're being passed as `java -d64 -ms3G -mx3G -cp example.jar -Djava.security.policy=policy com.example.JavaClass $1 Default Default Name Has Spaces"` which fails because the Java class only expects three total arguments.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why or how to make the arguments pass correctly?

Comment: I suspect you need to add an extra set of quotes, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: @corsiKa Nope, unfortunately that doesn't seem to change a thing. I've tried that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're quoting the `"`, which prevents it from quoting the arguments. Just remove the backslashes, and you should be set:

```
x=${2:-'Default'}
y=${3:-'Default Name Has Spaces'}
echo "$x"
echo "$y"
java -d64 -ms3G -mx3G -cp example.jar -Djava.security.policy=policy com.example.JavaClass $1 "$x" "$y"
```

Comment: Wow -- it was that simple...Can you tell I program in things like Java and .NET too often?? Thanks a lot, @ruakh. I appreciate the quick and helpful response!